# Is this Ember tutorial out of date?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I was trying to play around with a toy program from a very well written tutorial, but I get an ember error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The attempt to link-to route '<App.Contributor:ember296>' failed. The router did not find '<App.Contributor:ember296>' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'error', 'contributors', 'contributor', 'index', 'application' ember-1.5.1.js:73
Ember.assert ember-1.5.1.js:73
computeLinkViewRouteArgs ember-1.5.1.js:37699
```

I believe this is because this tutorial is from Feb 2013. I am using this version of ember among other libraries.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/handlebars-1.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ember-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Are there any ember experts that can look at the code at the bottom of the tutorial: [Tutorial](http://twbrandt.github.io/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide/) and see why it does not work? I am really stumped and I was hoping to mess around with the source code.

Comment: between feb 2013 and now there are some amount of changes but still you can make it work by doing few correction unless it is using ember-data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that's really out of date in the tutorial is that `linkTo` is deprecated in favor of `link-to` (they made a move of using dashed helper names).

Here's the app working.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kosutiha/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for positing a working version of the demo, it appears that you were right about "linkTo" needing to be "link-to" and also there were some necessary '' around the text contributor too. Now I have a base to work from, thanks!